# Powershell Script to Export All Groups and Members Assigned for a given OU to a CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to export all groups and the members assigned (if any) for a given OU.  How do I include groups with no members?

```
Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=BI-Security,OU=BH-Security Groups,DC=bh,DC=intra" | Foreach {
$Group = $_
Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group | `
select  @{Expression={$Group.Name};Label="Group Name"},Name | `
Export-CSV C:\Scripts\BIGroups.CSV -NoTypeInformation -append
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `Get-ADGroupMember` inside a calculated property with `Select-Object`:

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=BI-Security,OU=BH-Security Groups,DC=bh,DC=intra'
$groups |Select-Object @{Expression={$_.Name};Label='Group Name'},@{Expression={@(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_|Select -Expand Name) -join ';'};Label='Name'} | Export-CSV C:\Scripts\BIGroups.CSV -NoTypeInformation -append
```

Comment: Thanks!  I would have never came up with that.